# Magnitude of shear stress on beam element

Tags: beam, shear

In a [previous question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50599/direction-of-shear-in-beam-cross-section-how-to-understand-the-convention), the existence of a horizontal shear stress in a cantilevered I-beam with one free end was resolved. Here I'd like to explore the magnitude of the shear stress.  Consider an I-beam as shown below. The beam has a vertical load applied at the free end, and we'll examine a differential element of length dZ. Within the element, we select a sub-element for further examination.

[image: Cantilevered Beam with Free End and Load]

Before examining the stresses on the sub-element (hereafter referred to as the element), we state some assumptions.

1. The bending moment at any particular location along Z is constant.
2. The bending stress at any particular location along Z depends only on Y.
3. There are three free surfaces on the element (+X,-Y,+Y), each with zero shear stress.

When we examine the element, we see that the normal stress on each of the Z faces is due to a bending moment that increases with distance from the free end and varies with y, and so

$F_{_{-Z}} = F_{_{+Z}} + \left( \frac{dF}{dZ} \right) dZ$

and thus

$F_{_{-Z}} - F_{_{+Z}} = \left( \frac{dF}{dZ} \right) dZ$

A force balance in the Z-direction allows us to infer that there is a shear stress acting on the -X face of magnitude equal to the difference between the normal forces on the Z faces. Thus

$\tau_{_{-X}} dZ \Delta Y = \left( \frac{dF}{dZ} \right) dZ = \frac{d}{dZ} \left( \frac{1}{\Delta Y} \int \sigma A dY\right) dZ = \frac{d}{dZ} \left( \frac{A}{\Delta Y} \int \frac{MY}{I} dY\right) dZ$

Where A is the area subjected to normal forces, i.e., $A = \Delta X \Delta Y$, and I is the area moment of inertia.

The last expression can be simplified further as

$\frac{d}{dZ} \left( \frac{MA}{I} \int \frac{Y}{\Delta Y} dY\right) dZ = \frac{dM}{dZ} \frac{A \bar Y}{I} dZ = \frac{V A \bar Y}{I} dZ$

Where V is the shear stress on the Z faces. Now we can solve for the shear stress

$\tau_{_{-X}} dZ \Delta Y = \frac{V A \bar Y}{I} dZ \rightarrow \tau_{_{-X}} = \frac{V A \bar Y}{I \Delta Y }$

At last we have a value for the shear stress on the -X face, and the magnitude matches the textbook value. We can use this to find the shear stress mentioned at the beginning: that on the Z faces. A moment balance about an axis ***parallel the the Y-axis and passing through the centroid of the element*** shows

$\tau_{_{-X}} dZ \Delta Y \frac{\Delta X}{2} = \tau_{_{-Z}} \Delta Y \Delta X \frac{dZ}{2} + \tau_{_{+Z}} \Delta Y \Delta X \frac{dZ}{2}$

Or, more simply

$\tau_{_{-X}}  = \tau_{_{-Z}} + \tau_{_{+Z}}$

A force balance in the X-direction requires $\tau_{_{-Z}} = \tau_{_{+Z}}$, so the expression for $\tau_{_{\pm Z}}$ becomes

$\tau_{_{\pm Z}} = \frac{\tau_{_{-X}}}{2}$

**My textbook shows that these are equal, and so there is no factor of two. Can someone help me find my mistake?**

Comment: Your statements and equations contain many mistakes that are difficult to list all, and the mistakes have caused the erroneous result. I suggest providing the part in the reference that you don't seem to follow/understand. Prior to that, I suggest this post shall be closed.

Comment: Just so I understand,  you are saying that with "many mistakes" I somehow managed to get the correct value for both the magnitude and direction of one shear stress and the value for the other shear stress within a factor of two?  Strange.

Comment: As a minimum, you need to review the statement "1. The bending moment at any particular location along Z is constant." - As z is the axial axis of the loading span, for a cantilever subject to a concentrated load at its tip, how can the moment be constant?.

Answer (score 0):

Review **Assumption 1** because with a lumped force applied at the free end you obtain a z-dependent bending moment (i.e. M = F * z, with z entering from the free end, or  M = (L-x)*F with your coordinates system and with L the beam length).

In addition, just to clarify, one of the beam model assumption is that X and Y faces are not loaded.

Pictures below are taken from a *Structure* course lesson of my Eng. university (Credits: Politecnico di Milano).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is to check with assumption 1. At any particular value of z, the bending moment is constant - EXACTLY as you show: M = F * z  Note that M is not a function of x or y... it is constant at that particular value of z.  So what would I change when we agree??  

For example. Say L = 9, and z = 1. Then the bending moment at that z is F - a constant value independent of where in x and y we look.  If z = 4, then z is 4F - a constant independent of where in x and y we look. 

Other than that, I will look over your information and see if it helps. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Ok so the right way to say it is: _Bending moment is constant at any particular location inside every section whose perpendicular axis is parallel to the z-axis._

Answer (score 0):

The shear stress on the sub-element that you considered is actually zero.

I'll give you two inputs from my side and perhaps an amalgamation of them would help you solve your query.

---

1. 

Refer to the derivation below for the **longitudinal** shear stress at any x , which I'm calling $\tau_x$ (which is your $\tau_{xz}$).

[image]

Using this relation you can determine at any x the value of longitudinal shear stress. At x=0, i.e. on the extreme end of the I-section the longitudinal shear stress is zero. It increases as x increases to a maximum somewhat at  the center of the I-section.

2.

I consider an element between two sections, x and x+dx.

[image]

The longitudinal shear stress on this element's faces can be determined by using the formula derived above. Since the distance dx is differential the shear stresses on faces x and x+dx can be assumed equal. Let us now try taking moment about the green axis as I show in the figure. The moment of the forces due to normal stress will be zero and the shear stresses $\tau_x$ and $\tau_{x+dx}$ make an antickw moment which needs to be balanced by a ckw moment due to transverse shear stresses $\tau_z$ and $\tau_{z+dz}$

i.e.

$$(\tau_x h dz) . dx= (\tau_z h dx) .dz$$

$$\tau_x = \tau_z$$

or in other words the longitudinal shear stress is equal to the transverse shear stress in an element taken at any x.

---

Using idea 1, you can determine the longitudinal shear stress at any x, and using idea 2 the longitudinal shear stress will be equal to the transverse shear stress in any element taken at x.

Comment: Part two of your exercise is an interesting approach that differs a bit from what I was after, but it is relevant.  You found that if we take a slice wholly inside the flange, then the two stresses are equal (this is what I was trying to find), and I am fine with that as far as it goes. Yet when we take a piece that includes the lateral side (my approach) we do not find them equal. Would you agree with my analysis, given that we include the free surface in the element? If so, how do we reconcile these?  I think this gets me closer. Thanks again.

Comment: If we say that an element that includes the lateral side (+X, a free surface) has zero shear stress, then how is this acting on the adjacent (next-in-line) element to produce a shear stress on the corresponding face?  Your solution seems to be fine until we include the free surface, and then all shear disappears?? I am having a hard time making physical sense of that.

Comment: Happy to be of any help Karlton. This is what I think regarding the argument that you present - When we take an element with free surface the shear stress on it approaches zero, the shear stress on the next in line element is also very close to zero but less close to zero as the previous element. The shear doesn't disappear all of a sudden. Imagine you're making differential increments from x=0 and taking different elements, the shear stress on these elements will increase very slowly.

Comment: However, I understand what you're chasing. If we start with an element taken at x=0, the shear stress should turn out to be zero. I'll make an edit as soon as I come up with something.

Comment: @Karlton Try taking the moment about a vertical axis which passes through the centroid of the face which has the shear stress $\tau_{xz}$ acting on it, you would find that $\tau_{zx} = C. dM$, where C will be a constant. Since dM is differential change in BM, $\tau_{xz} ----> 0$